# WHERE IN crashing MySQL

Tags: mysql, myisam

I have two tables:

packages and package_to_tag both running MyISAM

the tables are structured as follows:

**packages**

```
+----------------+------------------+----------------+
|   aid(primary) |     source       |   date(index)  |
+----------------+------------------+----------------+
|   1            |    CA            |   2013-04-05   |
+----------------+------------------+----------------+
|   2            |    FL            |   2013-05-05   |
+----------------+------------------+----------------+
|   3            |    UT            |   2012-06-13   |
+----------------+------------------+----------------+
|   4            |    VT            |   2011-04-29   |
+----------------+------------------+----------------+
|   5            |    CT            |   2013-04-10   |
+----------------+------------------+----------------+
```

**package_to_tag** unique index on package-tag and both package_aid and tag have indexes

```
+---------------+------------------+
|  package_aid  |     tag          |
+---------------+------------------+
|   2           |    sports        |
+---------------+------------------+
|   2           |    nba           |
+---------------+------------------+
|   1           |    food          |
+---------------+------------------+
|   1           |    burrito       |
+---------------+------------------+
|   4           |    hockey        |
+---------------+------------------+
|   4           |    sports        |
+---------------+------------------+
|   3           |    news          |
+---------------+------------------+
|   5           |    sports        |
+---------------+------------------+
|   5           |    nba           |
+---------------+------------------+
```

so my basic query to find out which packages have both sports and nba as tags is:

```
SELECT package_aid FROM package_to_tag
WHERE tag IN("sports","nba")
GROUP BY package_aid
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

This works great until I try and add a date sort to the results.  (keep in mind my package record set is somewhere in the 400k range)

My query to get the source based on the matching tags is:

```
SELECT package_aid, source 
FROM package_to_tag
RIGHT JOIN packages ON packages.aid = package_to_tag.package_aid
AND tag IN("sports","nba")
GROUP BY package_aid
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 500
```

Which, with 400k records, takes up to 5 seconds easy.  Unless I remove the `date` sort.  Then it takes less than a second.  So, since I always had decent success with the IN statement I tried narrowing down my initial result set with something like:

```
SELECT aid,source FROM packages
WHERE aid IN(
  SELECT package_aid FROM package_to_tag
  WHERE tag IN("sports","nba")
  GROUP BY package_aid
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
)
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 500
```

I figured I'd only be applying the sort to about 8-10k records instead of the whole record set.

But, This just flat out pegs the database at 100% utilization and I'm forced to reboot.... Even if I narrow down the inner select with extra tags to a total of 80 records or less.

I tried running just this query:

```
SELECT package_aid FROM package_to_tag
WHERE tag IN("sports","nba")
GROUP BY package_aid
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

This returns 8-10k records within a second.

What am I missing?

Comment: what are you indexs ?

Comment: @user1281385, not sure what you mean... you mean what TYPE of indexes?

Comment: order by date means you will benifit from a date index searching for aid in means you will benifit from a aid index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Earlier versions of MySQL had problems in optimizing `in` with subqueries.  An easy solution is to rewrite it as an `exists` clause:

```
SELECT aid,source FROM packages
WHERE exists (
  SELECT package_aid
  FROM package_to_tag
  WHERE tag IN("sports","nba") and package_aid = packages.aid
  GROUP BY package_aid
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
)
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 500
```

Having an index on `package_to_tag(pages.aid, tag)` should be a big help performance-wise.

Comment: Excellent.  It pains me that I've spent so long on this and it came down to switching from IN to EXISTS.  But, it worked wonderfully.  Thank you.